# Can I push/pop the value of the SetOverwrite flag in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

Inside a function or macro, I frequently need specific [SetOverwrite](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Reference/SetOverwrite) behavior. However, I prefer to have these subprograms clean up after themselves (not leaving non-return values on the stack, keeping the OutPath the same, not altering global states, etc.) so that I don't have to copy a stream of settings commands every time I want to do something—in order to keep the code more readable.

Is there a way to accomplish this with `SetOverwrite`? Can I "detect" it, save it, and restore it somehow?

There's no `GetOverwrite` function that I can see. The SetOverwrite docs refer to the "overwrite flag," though I can't find concrete references to what exactly that is. Is there a way I can get the value of this (or an arbitrary) flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save the current state of the flag in a variable, but `SetOverwrite` allows you to use `lastused` as an argument, which restores the value of the flag which was used before the last `SetOverwrite`. So you cannot save the flag recursively, but you can set it temporary before `File` and restore it after it:

```nsis
${If} $something = "whatever"
  SetOverwrite on
${Else}
  SetOverwrite ifnewer
${EndIf}

File "foo.txt"

SetOverwrite lastused
```

Answer (score 1):

No there is no flag you can interact with. There is a set of flags that can be controlled by plug-ins but the overwrite mode is not one of them.

I think the overwrite mode interacts with the `File` instruction and therefore has some compile-time restrictions.

The only thing you can do is

```nsis
${If} $something = "whatever"
  SetOverwrite on
${Else}
  SetOverwrite ifnewer
${EndIf}

File "foo.txt"
```

`SetOverwrite` applies to all other `File` instructions later in the script so it is a shame there is no way to push/pop its state.

From the documentation:

> 4.8.2 Compiler Flags
>
> The following commands affect how the compiler generates code and compresses data. Unless otherwise noted, these commands are valid anywhere in the script and affect every line below where each one is placed (until overridden by another command). They cannot be jumped over using flow control instructions.